# Closed vs. Hidden Web Part - what is the difference?

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-designer, page-layout, hidden

What is the difference between "Hidden Web Part" and "Closed Web Pat"?

PS.
I tried to search on the internet but could only find "deleting vs. closing" web parts

Sharepoint 2010 (Sharepoint Designer 2010)

Update (due to one of confusing answers to this question):
The quote from [1. p.119]:

> Tip   Closed Web Parts can increase the time it takes for a browser to
>   load the page. Keep the number of closed Web Parts to a minimum and
>   only close a Web Part when you want to temporarily hide a Web Part and
>   its customizations. In the browser, you can find closed Web Parts by
>   first placing a page in edit mode. Then, on the Editing Tools, Insert
>   tab on the server ribbon, click Web Part, and under Categories, click
>   Closed Web Parts. The Closed Web Parts category appears only if the
>   page contains closed Web Parts.

Cited:
[1]
Penelope Coventry
Microsoft® SharePoint® Designer 2010 Step by Step.
O’Reilly Media, Inc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Closed Webpart >** When you close a webpart , it goes and stays in the closed webpart gallery. You can see this gallery when you click on Edit Page on the 2010 ribbon > Insert >  Webpart > Closed Webpart Gallery.

When you close a webpart it does not get loaded in the webpage during realtime. The closed webparts even then reside in this gallery which can be reused anytime in the future.

**Hidden Webpart >** These webparts can be deployed through visual studio and can be loaded in the page during realtime however wont appear to the user in the webbrowser.

Answer (score 1):

On a simple definition, I would say that an hidden webpart is still loaded in the webpage, a closed one no.